# Unrecognized Selector with OHGridView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gridview

I downloaded the OHGridView hoping that it was the answer to all my problems.

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHGridView

I did all that it said to do (add the class files, add the code, and change a few other things).

I went to build it and it crashed. I realized the lines of code why it was crashing:

```
((OHGridView *)self.view).rowHeight = 100;
((OHGridView *)self.view).columnsCount = 2;
```

Error from Console:

```
`-[UIView setRowHeight:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b55110
2011-02-20 09:01:16.906 TableView[14358:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setRowHeight:]: unrecognized  selector sent to instance 0x4b55110'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00e4dbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00fa25c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00e4f6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00dbf366 ___forwarding___ + 966
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00dbef22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   TableView                           0x00004232 -[DetailViewController viewDidLoad] + 831
6   UIKit                               0x0037165e -[UIViewController view] + 179
7   UIKit                               0x0036fa57 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
8   UIKit                               0x00380201 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
9   UIKit                               0x0037e831 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
10  UIKit                               0x0037fa86 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 326
11  UIKit                               0x0037a606 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
12  UIKit                               0x0038183e -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 932
13  UIKit                               0x0037a4a0 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
14  TableView                           0x00002e4f -[RootViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 681
15  UIKit                               0x00339794 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1140
16  UIKit                               0x0032fd50 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
17  Foundation                          0x000427f6 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00e2efe3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00e30594 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00d8ccc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00d8c240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00d8c161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
23  GraphicsServices                    0x016ef268 GSEventRunModal + 217
24  GraphicsServices                    0x016ef32d GSEventRun + 115
25  UIKit                               0x002d242e UIApplicationMain + 1160
26  TableView                           0x00001abc main + 102
27  TableView                           0x00001a4d start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException`
```

I removed them and it loaded fine but I didn't see any content.

Please help,
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a clone of the repository just now and then did a build and run of his example project without making any changes to the code. It ran without any warnings or errors.

You'll need to check your code wherever you made changes.
**update after your comment**
`Unrecognized Selector` often means that you have a capitalization error or that your code isn't the kind of object that you think it is.
For example: I can get almost the same error that you get if I try to call the `setRowHeight:` directly against a `OHGridView` object instead of the `view` property of the object, like this

```
    ((OHGridView*)self).rowHeight = 100;
((OHGridView*)self).columnsCount = 2;
```

So, I would check your code to make sure that your object is an OHGridView and that you are setting the rowHeight property of the view of the OHGridView.

Comment: I did the same thing but when trying to put it in my other project, it crashed. I have edited the post and put my error from the console.

Comment: Thanks! I checked and I didn't assign the view to OHGridView... Silly me!